# Why are the Goal Conversions different in Overview than in the Funnel within Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Goal setup in Google Analytics as a Destination type goal. It was previously working, and just noticed that it stopped.

I thought it was completely broken after seeing the Funnel, but when I went to check under:

```
Conversions > Goals > Overview
```

I noticed that conversions are being tracked, so no sure what the problem is. Thanks!

[image: Goal Setup]

[image: Goal Funnel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Funnel Visualization is not the best report to monitor conversions. Take a look at the specifics of this report: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en
For example,  when you mark a first step as required, the Funnel Visualization report only includes goal conversions that pass through that required step. Other sessions are just dropped from the report.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up about the funnel, but I'm wondering why on the Home dashboard in GA it still shows as 0 in conversion rate.

Comment: The Conversion Rate shown in the first dashboard widget on GA Home, linking to the Audience overview is definitely using a strange conversion rate calculation. If you scroll down to the How are you performing against goals? section, it will show the Goal Conversion Rate as shown in the Goals overview report.

Comment: In GA home Dashboard (Audience overview) section, the conversion rate shown is the e-commerce conversion rate which is calculated based on the formula:
Ecommerce conversion rate = (Transaction/Sessions)*100
Transaction value taken from E-commerce Overview Report
Sessions value taken from Audience Overview Report